# gevent + flask seems to block

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I want to run a background worker in the same script as flask is running and flask seems to be blocking which I guess is understandable. Pretty much I want a script to check key system metrics every second so I don't want to use something like celery or a big queueing system to do it.

Simple code example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gevent
from flask import Flask


class Monitor:
    def __init__(self, opts):
        self.opts = opts

    def run(self):
        print "do something: %i" % self.opts

        gevent.sleep(1)

        self.run()


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []

    for mon in [1,2]:
        monitor = Monitor(mon)
        threads.append(gevent.spawn(monitor.run))


    threads.append(gevent.spawn(app.run))

    gevent.joinall(threads)
```

My output looks like

```
$ ./so.py
do something: 1
do something: 2
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

If I remove the theads.append for the app.run it runs fine. Is this possible to do or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

add in your script next two lines:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

before the line:

```
from flask import Flask
```

and all be OK

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up handling the issue using apscheduler v2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gevent
import time
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

class Monitor:
    def __init__(self, opts):
        self.opts = opts

    def run(self):
        @sched.interval_schedule(seconds=1)
        def handle_run():
            print "do something: %i" % self.opts


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for mon in [1,2]:
        monitor = Monitor(mon)
        monitor.run()

    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the below:

`class Monitor:
    def init(self, opts):
        self.opts = opts
    def run(self):
        While True:
            print "do something: %i" % self.opts
            gevent.sleep(1)`

and then maybe don't joinall, since it doesn't seem like you really want to wait for them to complete before doing something else.

You may also need to put a try/except statement inside the while loop, and respawn if there is an error that kills the greenlet.